# Multivariate Nonlinear Mixed Effects Model

Tags: mixed-model, multivariate-analysis, random-effects-model, nonlinear-regression

I want to estimate a multivariate nonlinear mixed effect models where the random effects are not assumed to be normal. What approach should I take ?

Answer (score 2):

You could adopt a Bayesian approach where you can specify the random effects to follow whatever distribution you want, provided it is supported by the software you use.

WinBUGS, JAGS and Stan should all be able to do this, with multivariate responses. You could use the native software itself, or call it from within, for example, R or Python.

Comment: But the estimation methods of multivariate nonlinear mixed effect model that I used is not Bayesian method such as pseudo penalized  least square,laplacian approximation,pseudo EM, Month Carlo EM and the random effect is not normal.

Comment: So my suggestion is to switch to a Bayesian model, which will be able to fit the model you want.